# python import module issue

Tags: python, python-3.5

Время от времени сталкиваюсь с проблемой импортов в `python`  получая ошибки

```
ImportError: No module named 'xxxx'
```

имею приблизительно следующую стутуру проекта

```
my_project/
│
├── src/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   └── module1.py
│
├── utils/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── logger.py
│   └── constants.py
│
├── logs/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── app.log
│
├── config/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── config_file.yaml
│
├── run.sh
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
```

версия python 3.5
запускаю через `sh`

```
~/scripts/env/bin/python ~/scripts/en/my_project/src/main.py
```

в каталогах где присутствуют файлы для импорта добавил пустые файлы `__init__.py` это к сожалению не помогает, при запуске получаю ошибки

```
.../src/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from utils.logger import info, error
ImportError: No module named 'utils'
```

Просьба, подсказать, как можно решить данную проблему с импортами?

Comment: Чтобы питон знал, где искать модуль utils, папка, в которой он находится, должна быть прописана в sys.path или PYTHONPATH

Comment: А ещё нехорошо создавать настолько абстрактные названия для модулей верхнего уровня — например, ваш модуль config имеет название, совпадающее с [другим модулем config](https://docs.red-dove.com/cfg/python.html), что означает, что пользователь вашего проекта не сможет установить их одновременно из-за конфликтов имён

Comment: @andreymal здравствуйте, есть пару проектов с аналогичной структурой которые лежат рядом и запускается без каких либо ошибок, при том что не прописывал sys.path,

Comment: Тогда перепроверьте, что вы запускаете всё именно находясь в папке проекта

Comment: Кажется, без sys.path обойтись трудно.  Есть вариант, написать в `run.sh` `python3 -c 'import src.main'`, только при этом в `main.py`  `__name__` будет `src.main`